# Pressing tab after sourcing script file prints script related output

Tags: shell, scripting

I have a script file in a directory. Its contents are as follows :

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                                                                                       

function set {

    cur=`pwd`

    alias m="cd $cur/app/models"
    alias v="cd $cur/app/views"
    alias t="cd $cur/app/views/templates"
    alias c="cd $cur/app/controllers"
    alias cl="cd $cur/app/classes"

    alias con="cd $cur/config"
    alias p="cd $cur/public"
}

function unset {
    unalias m v t c cl con p
}

if [ $1 = 's' ]; then
    set 
elif [ $1 = 'u' ]; then
    unset
fi
```

When I haven't yet sourced this file, there is no problem. However, once I source this file using the command `. script.sh`, whenever I type a command like `cd` or `vim` and then type something and press the `tab` button, this is what I get :

```
cd abash: unalias: m: not found
bash: unalias: v: not found
bash: unalias: t: not found
bash: unalias: c: not found
bash: unalias: cl: not found
bash: unalias: con: not found
bash: unalias: p: not found
bash: _upvars: -v: missing argument(s)
bash: unalias: m: not found
bash: unalias: v: not found
bash: unalias: t: not found
bash: unalias: c: not found
bash: unalias: cl: not found
bash: unalias: con: not found
bash: unalias: p: not found
bash: _upvars: -v: missing argument(s)
```

Any idea what happens and how to stop it?

Comment: BY the way, setting aliases like this is not a good idea either. See [here](http://superuser.com/q/708462/151431) for more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're defining functions called `set` and `unset`. This is a really bad idea, because your complection module seems to *call* set or unset (which are part of POSIX), expecting to use the shell builtins, but it ends up getting your function instead.

Name your functions something else other than `set` and `unset` (if you really must name them that, prepend an underscore).

As an aside, there's no reason to create functions as `function foo { ... }`. Just use `foo() { ... }` instead -- it's part of POSIX, whereas the form you are using is not.

Comment: The same thing could be said for `set` as well, which is also a POSIX built-in.

Comment: Wow! I didn't know about that. Should have noted the syntax highlighting. Thanks guys :)